# Swift/macOS - force playing audio through speaker

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, avaudioplayer

Here ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29548280/5685345)) can be found a method (related to `AVAudioSession`) to force playing audio through iPhone speaker.  However, on macOS, there seems no such a class `AVAudioSession`.  Is it possible to force playing audio through speaker on macOS (btw also with the max volume)?  Thank you.

Comment: Did you get the answer? I'm searching for one.