# Terminating app due to failure in assertBarrierOnQueue threading violation: expected the main thread

Tags: ios, avplayer, swift5, xcode13

My app is getting crashed when App is in backGround and i received webrtc call from Notification.

```
 func appClient(_ client: ARDAppClient!, didChange state: RTCIceConnectionState) {
    switch state {
    case .connected:
        
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        if (delegate != nil){
            delegate?.appClientStatus!(client, status: .connected)
        }
        captureController?.startCapture()
        
 
        do {
            try audioSession.overrideOutputAudioPort(.speaker) // App is crashing here
        } catch _ {
            
        }
        
        break
    case .disconnected:
        if (delegate != nil){
            delegate?.appClientStatus!(client, status: ARDAppClientState.disconnected)
        }
        print("disconnected ICE")
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

I've tried different ways and patches

- **Main thread**

  ```
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
        do{
            try audioSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord)
            try audioSession.overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSession.PortOverride.speaker)
        }catch let error{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
  }
  ```
- **setActive**

  ```
     do {
       try audioSession.setActive(true)
     } catch _ {

     }
     do {
      try audioSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord)
     } catch _ {
     }

     do {
        try audioSession.overrideOutputAudioPort(.speaker)
     } catch _ {

     }
  ```

From below reference -

[AVAudioSession - How to switch between speaker and headphones output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52390659/avaudiosession-how-to-switch-between-speaker-and-headphones-output)

[Force audio file playback through iPhone loud speaker using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29526435/force-audio-file-playback-through-iphone-loud-speaker-using-swift)

*But still app is getting crashed and throwing below error*:-

- **error**

> failure in assertBarrierOnQueue of FBSSerialQueue:0x28294f100 (FBSSerialQueue.m:121) : threading violation: expected the main thread

[image: Thread]

[image: Debug log error]

Comment: Have you get its solution

Comment: I am getting same error